# Is it possible to change he/she (he or she) in a sentence into one word?

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to change he/she (he or she) in a sentence into one word? For instance: When a student comes in, ask him or her to...

Comment: Them/they/their - A good way to replace he/she

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say **when a student comes in, ask them to hand in their homework**. It is very common in English to see the personal pronoun *them* used in a gender-neutral fashion. When *they* is used like that, it is called [**the singular they**](https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/):

> **Singular they** has become the pronoun of choice to replace *he* and *she* in cases where the gender of the antecedent – the word the pronoun refers to – is unknown, irrelevant, or nonbinary, or where gender needs to be concealed. It’s the word we use for sentences like *Everyone loves his mother*.